# oracle apex mobile apps

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have turn my oracle apex web application to mobile. I am facing an issue with apex header over lapsing the mobile phone header.

i thought that i can change the header and the body top position with CSS. but when i did that , when user scroll we can see region going up (see picture 2)

Any help how to solve this?

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the apex version, apex theme that you are using?

Comment: What's the actual problem? What CSS did you try? Does the problem exist on a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my web url inside flutter webview to make it accessible on playstore.
Apex is not really a native mobile app so the issue was the apex application navigation bar was overlapsing the mobile phone navbar.

Solution
i just have to add an appbar within the wrapper.

```
 return new MaterialApp(
   home: new WebviewScaffold(url: 'https://www.your_apex_app_url.com',
     appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1.0),
    child: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ),
   
  ),
```

Thanks.